# Wordpress - Change Multisite 'Site Added' Message

Tags: php, wordpress, function, multisite

I am looking to change the updated message that is displayed when adding a new site in wordpress multisite. I know I can go in and update the wp-admin/network/site-new.php but I am wanted to add to my functions file for to avoid update errors.

Comment: Does my solution works?  Let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace in HTML by using java-script.
Just need to replace text 'Site Added.' with your own custom message.
Here is the complete code that you need to add to your plugin.

```
function custom_admin_js() {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript' > 

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Site added.','custom message');

 </script>";

}
add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_js');
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Works on the text. Going to adjust to bring in links etc. Thanks

Comment: Increased your reputation by Up voting your question... :)